# Template query: Advanced section query to get unique items from custom entry type field

Tags: craft3, querystring

I'm trying to build a filter for a blog section in Craft 3.

I'm fairly new to Craft and my client now wants a dropdown filter where they can filter out authors. Thus, I want to write a query that fetches a unique list of authors from my blog channel structure.

The structure is: 
section: `blogEntries` (Channel) with an entry type `blogEntry`.

Each `blogEntry` has a `content` (matrix) and and `writer` entry field which is connected to one or more `employee` entries.

So; `blogEntries > blogEntry > writer(s) > employee`

What I want is something like

```
craft.entries.section('blogEntries').column('writer').distinct().all()
```

This is what I have:

```
{# Way too slow #}
{% for item in craft.entries.section('blogEntries').all() %}
    {% if item.writer|length %}
        {% set person = item.writer.one() %}
        {% set name =  person.firstname ~ (person.surname|length ? ' ' ~ person.surname : '') %}
        {% if name not in writers %}
            {% set writers = writers|merge([name]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Terrible solution, terrible performance.

How can I improve this code? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Return all ids for your posts' section
{% set postIds = craft.entries.section('blogEntries').ids() %}

// Look for and return employees which have a relation with any of the posts returned in 'postIds'
{% set writers = craft.entries.section('employee').relatedTo({ sourceElement: entryIds }).all() %}

// Loop and display
{% for writer in writers %}
    {{ writer.title }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

This will only return a list of writers who have written a post, not a list of all writers but I guess that's what you want..?

Comment: This worked like a charm and it's so obviously the way to go about it. Really impressed with how powerful the relatedTo method is as well! Thanks!